# How do I get intellisense working with Spark and FluentHtml?

Tags: intellisense, spark-view-engine, mvccontrib

I have Spark view engine registered with my MVC app and it works great :-)

I have a problem however getting FluentHtml extension method intellisense working on my views. I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem?

This code works: `<%= this.TextBox(x => x.Name) %>` But I dont get intellisense?

I have intellisense working for everyhting else. For example `<%= Html.TextBox(...) %>` works.

Answer (score 1):

The intellisense is a bit flakey at times. 
I'm assuming you have the intellisense VS package installed? If not, install it and give it a go.

Are you running ReSharper? If so, while in the spark view, go into ReSharpers options and set the code completion to the "Visual Studio" option. ReSharper takes over the native C# language instellisense. Setting the setting back to Visual Studio fixes this. Its a bit of a pain, but right now there is a small resharper add in that is being developed to detect spark views and switch it for you automatically.

Comment: Hi there... thanks for the post. Do you have any further references to the add in you mention?

Comment: Fixed the issue with no intellesense with r#